# Can I solve this blood question by re-arranging?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rearrangement-inequality

I believe the answer to the question in the attached image is the 4th bubble. Be careful not to accidentally miss the formula under the worded explanation, at the bottom of the image.

The unit litre/gram is equivalent to C = something, so rearrange the equation. **My reasoning:**

> F = Q/C

Multiply both sides by C.

> CF = Q

Divide by F to get C on its own.

> C = Q/F

Could someone please check if my thought process was correct, and if I have done the algebra in the optimal way?

[Blood equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eesCu.jpg)

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Looks ok to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct.

We can check by using the units to see if we get back the correct equation.

Starting with

$$\dfrac {\text {liter}}{\text {minute}} = \dfrac {\text {grams/minute}}{\text {grams/liter}}$$

Multiply by $\dfrac {\text {grams/liter}}{\text {grams/minute}}$  to get $$\text {liter}\cdot \text {grams/liter} = \text {minute}\cdot \text {grams/minute}$$

Divide by $\text {liter}$ to get $$\dfrac {\text {grams}}{\text {liter}} = \dfrac {\text {grams}}{\text {minute}} \cdot \dfrac {\text {minute}}{\text {liter}}$$

Transform to a division problem by inverting the $\dfrac {\text {minute}}{\text {liter}}$ to get $$\dfrac {\text {grams}}{\text {liter}} = {\dfrac {\text {grams}}{\text {minute}} \div \dfrac {\text {liter}}{\text {minute}}}$$

Since $C$ is $\text {grams/liter}$, $Q$ is $\text {grams/minute}$ and $F$ is $\text {liter/minute}$, we have $$C = \dfrac QF$$ as desired.

Comment: I personally find it easier to calculate this with just C, Q, and F variables. I have no idea what a cross multiply is.

Comment: I've edited my post to take out the cross-multiplication reference.